# no_proxy for subnet or range of ips

Tags: networking, server, proxy

I have machine connected to 2 Nets, some for my local network I want bypass (not go through) proxy:

How define no_proxy for range of local network for example 192.168.100.0/24

This syntax 192.168.100.0/24 works in browser definition however it seems int is not working in /etc/environment or no_proxy setting!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no syntax available for no_proxy which would cover a subnet. The only solution I am aware of is to generate the whole list with something like

`export no_proxy=${no_proxy},$(echo 192.168.100.{1..255} | sed 's/ /,/g')`

Comment: Sources for this? It really seems to depend on which binary makes use of these binaries. And interpretations [appear to differ](https://superuser.com/a/1166790/75914).

Comment: Which part of that link contradicts my answer? It also states no_proxy covers only hosts, not subnets

Answer (score 0):

Since [version 7.86.0 (October 2022)](https://github.com/curl/curl/releases?q=7.86.0&expanded=true) at least `curl` supports the CIDR syntax for `no_proxy`. Since many applications are using `libcurl` they will indirectly inherit this feature.

From [curl documentation](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/libcurl/opts/CURLOPT_NOPROXY.3#L52-L55):
"Since 7.86.0, IP addresses specified to this option can be provided using CIDR
notation: an appended slash and number specifies the number of "network bits"
out of the address to use in the comparison. For example "192.168.0.0/16"
would match all addresses starting with "192.168"."

The original github issue: [no_proxy not support cidr](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/9773).
Some [examples can be found in curl's unit tests](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/tests/unit/unit1614.c#L58-L125).